# How to set url and callback url field for twitter app development?

Tags: node.js, npm, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to create a twitter application and got stuck on url and callback url field.

I am using it for personal project and hence I set url fields as `http://127.0.0.1/` but I get `Invalid website url` message.

What url should I enter?

Answer (score 1):

You should "real url".

URL of your server (can listen request from twitter), not `http://127.0.0.1/`, because it is local.

If they call to `http://127.0.0.1/`, just call to localhost of them, not is your computer.

Comment: yeah.. but in other solutions for the same, I have seen this solution.
so what can I do if I want to test it in my local machine and have no publicly accessible sites?

Comment: Are you using sign-in with Twitter and do you need a callback URL at all? if so, you *must* use a publically-accessible DNS name so that Twitter's API can actually perform the callback. If not, leave callback URL blank, and just set the URL field to something like `http://example.com`